# A deeper look at Spark's interaction with Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

I'm trying to understand the interaction between Spark and Hive metastore. I started by looking at the when and what calls are being made from Spark to Hive metastore. I could see a bunch of `get_table` calls for `spark.read.table` operations, and if the table is partitioned a couple of `get_partitions` calls when the DataFrame is materialized by invoking actions. Another thing that I noticed is that Spark doesn't cache the table definition. Every time an action is invoked on a Hive table, the definition and corresponding partitions are read from the underlying metastore, again!. I made peace with that considering Spark gives you other options to go about optimizing for situations like this, you could persist the DataFrame. I noticed something odd when I looked at the API invocation pattern for `saveAsTable` operation. There were API invocations for creating a table and for creating partitions as expected, but along with that, there were approx ~30 `get_table` calls being made to Hive metastore. I find it really strange and hard to understand the purpose of these calls.

I'm looking for answers to the following questions.

- Why doesn't Spark caches the table and partition information once it is read from the metastore?
- What is the rationale behind so many `get_table` calls, while creating a Hive table?
- Are the number of `get_table` calls made while reading or writing table, a function of the number of executors?
- Is there a scope of improvement, do we expect significant performance improvements by optimizing for the number of calls made to metastore?

Comment: "Every time an action is invoked on a Hive table, the definition and corresponding partitions are read from the underlying metastore, again!" - Why does that surprise you - another process may have altered the table.

Comment: @Terry Dactyl, Yes that would explain why the multiple calls. But i was thinking to have a control to say when to perform a reload and when to avoid.

Comment: @TerryDactyl, also, I'm not much worried about invoking get_tables or other actions whenever we are re-evaluating the DAG and it actually makes sense, as you mentioned. If you can help me understand relationship between number of API invocations and corresponding df operations, that will be a great help.